# How could I access the source code of a .one OneNote file?

Tags: ms-office, onenote

How could I access the source code of a .one OneNote file?

I've tried to rename the .one file to .zip as what happens with .doc files in order to access their source code, but .one doesn't seem to work like that.
Also, I've tried to open it with Notepad++, but it isn't in a plain-text format.

---

*I regard this as a programming question because:
I'm using content-editing-automation scripts (e.g. RegEx-related find and replace scripts). Accessing the source code of .one files helps me apply bulky automated edits on their content Using RegEx.*

Comment: How does this relate to programming?

Comment: I'm using text-automation scripts, like RegEx-related find and replace scripts. Accessing the source code for .one helps me applying bulky automated edits on content, or even format.

Comment: Have you tried to open it with a regular text editor like Notepad++? I'm not familar with the .one format but when its plain text based this may help. When not, you'll need a parser for this, which may hard on proprietär software like MS.

Comment: @Lion I've tried Notepad++ but unfortunately it isn't in a plain-text format.

Answer (score 2):

.one files aren't technically source code - they contain the data that describes the pages in a section and their content.

Opening them as text won't show you anything meaningful as they are binary data.
Microsoft has released the way this data is structured in .one files in the following documentation. You can use this to parse the binary file to obtain the information you need.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd924743(v=office.12).aspx

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/File-format-changes-in-OneNote-2016-for-Windows-a9129622-1755-470b-91e7-b2a461194036

Answer (score 0):

The .one file format is super-complicated as it has to store images and all revisions, so it's binary and not XML-based like the rest of the office suite

That said if you do want to see the XML structure of the notebook or specific page content you can use OMSpy:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnguin/2011/07/28/onenote-spy-omspy-for-onenote-2010/

It works fine for 2016 Desktop.